# How to draw android spinner option from JSON

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I am new to `android` development. I am stuck try to show dropdown's data into android . Data will come from server as a `json` format. I am using `volley` library for `HTTP` requests. Here is my `volley` response

```
{"blood_group_map":[{"value":"1","text":"O+"},{"value":"2","text":"O-"},{"value":"3","text":"A+"},{"value":"4","text":"A-"},{"value":"5","text":"B+"},{"value":"6","text":"B-"},{"value":"7","text":"AB+"},{"value":"8","text":"AB-"}]}
```

In this `response` I want draw `blood_group_map` key in `Spinner` option list like this `HTML`. Here `value` key is used for value and `text` key is used for display text.

```
<option value="1">O+</option>
```

**Update**:

I parsed this JSON but I want to send spiner value property to server and display text property. How can I send value to server not text ?

```
For Example if I select O+ blood group then I send spinner value 1 to server.
```

Comment: Parse and put that data into arrayList and pass it to adapter

Comment: check out this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-populating-spinner-json-tutorial/

Comment: Start with a getJSONArray("blood_group_map")

Comment: Note: you could use Retrofit instead of Volley in order to bypass manually parsing your json

Comment: Please see my updated question

Answer (score -1):

Use GSON parser to parse data to from json.

Basic working of GSON is: you build an object with structure same as your json.

All you have to do is pass it to spinner. An example of GSON parser here: [GSON parser example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Spinner example: [Spinner example](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)